# How to display output of a function in python?

Tags: python, function, output

I`m trying to make a simple conversion program but the output keeps coming out either weird or none at all. How do I fix this? Here is my code.

```
#crypto = [Bitcoin, Ethereum, XRP, Litecoin]
bitcoin = [1, 40.19, 38284.22, 168.73]
ethereum = [.025, 1, 951.99, 4.20]
xrp = [.000026, .001, 1, .003]
litecoin = [.0058, .231, 223.81, 1]

def crypto2Crypto(x,y,w):
    if(x == "BE"):
        w =+ (y * bitcoin[1])
    if(x == "XL"):
        y * xrp[3]
    if(x == "EB"):
        y * ethereum[0]
    if(x == "LX"):
        y * litecoin[2]

def main():
    print("Welcome to the Cryptocurrency exchange!")
    conversion = input('"What will you be converting today? B = Bitcoin, E = Ethereum, X = XRP, Litecoin = L. Please give an exchange with the following syntax crypto1crypto2, ex. type "BE" for Bitcoin to Ethereum."')
    amountOfCurrency = float(input("How much do you have of " + conversion[0] + " ?"))
    w = crypto2Crypto(conversion,amountOfCurrency,0)
    print(w)
main()
```

Comment: You don't return a value in your `crypto2Crypto` function so the final print will be None

Answer (score 2):

### Three problems

1. The `=+` operators(*yes, plural*) are not the same as the `+=` operator.

   - **An assignment (`=`)**

     ```py
     >>> a = 2
     >>> a =+ 1
     >>> a
     1
     ```

     Why? Because `a =+ 1` becomes `a = +1` ⇒ `a = 1`.
   - **An augmented assignment (`+=`)**

     ```py
     >>> a = 2
     >>> a += 1
     >>> a
     3
     ```

     Why? Because `a += 1` becomes `a = a + 1` ⇒ `a = 2 + 1` ⇒ `a = 3`. More on augmented assignments [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/simple_stmts.html#augmented-assignment-statements).
2. If you don't return some value from a function yourself, Python will automatically make it return `None`. So, you should add a `return` statement to `crypto2Crypto`. This has been shown in the solution in the next section.
3. Binary floating-point numbers (Python's `float` type, the one you used in `main` to get the value for `amountOfCurrency`) and their arithmetic are not accurate. Read The Python Tutorial's [chapter 15](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) for details.

### Solution

Change the `crypto2Crypto` function to:

```py
def crypto2Crypto(x, y, w):
    if x == "BE":
        w += (y * bitcoin[1])
    if x == "XL":
        w += (y * xrp[3])
    if x == "EB":
        w += (y * ethereum[0])
    if x == "LX":
        w += (y * litecoin[2])

    return w
```

As for the floating-point weirdness, you can use the built-in [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#round) function to round-off to the required number of decimal places.

Answer (score -1):

Append this to the end of crypto2Crypto function

```
return w
```

Not certain if w is what you need, but return what you need to